# GNU parallel ssh jobs: What happens to an incomplete job if the server dies?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Suppose we want to dispatch jobs to a collection of servers using GNU parallel. What would happen if one of the servers die(power failure, thermal shutdown...) while busy executing a job? Will GNU parallel just dispatch the same job to another server or will that job be lost forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be lost forever *unless* you use `--retries` in which case it will be retried on another server. Also have a look at `--filter-hosts` to remove hosts that are down.

Comment: Thanks looking at the man pages, its seems `--retries` is what I am looking for. It should work well in conjunction with `--resume-failed` if the job server might go down as well.

Answer (score 4):

It seems I should have read the man pages more carefully. We can resume failed jobs by saving a joblog file and resuming from there, like so: `parallel --resume-failed --joblog logfile`

I will delete this post if it is deemed to be of little value to anyone.